# How to tune performance of a temporal SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, temporal-database

For a given point in time, an asset has an effective price. Some assets have a new price once a week, some once a day. The most recent price is the "effective price".

The temporal table that stores the described relationship looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AssetPrice
(
    AssetId int NOT NULL -- FK to the table dbo.Asset
    ,EffectiveDate datetime NOT NULL
    ,Price decimal NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_AssetPrice PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AssetId,EffectiveDate,Price)
)
```

The data looks something like this:

```
AssetId    EffectiveDate    Price
-------    -------------    -----
      1       2012-01-11     1.21
      1       2012-01-12     1.22
      2       2012-01-11     3.55
      2       2012-01-12     3.60
      3       2012-01-04     5.15
      3       2012-01-11     5.14
```

To query for the effective price of an `AssetId` is simple, but it takes a non-trivial amount of time to calculate.

It is ideal to store the data physically, so that only data changes to `dbo.AssetPrice` requires a recalculation of the effective price. I believe I cannot create an indexed view because the pertinent aggregate functions are not allowed in an indexed view.

How do I tune the table to retrieve the effective price (most recent price) very quickly?

Comment: Which query takes a "non-trivial amount of time" to calculate the price?

Comment: @ypercube The query to find the effective price of an `AssetId` was the bottle neck in a few calculations - it required a subquery much like the one written by Rubens Farias in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can use two different approaches:

- Alter your table schema to include an interval. In this case, you need to store start AND end date to determine your effective *period*. With that, you just need to use a simple BETWEEN to get your desired price. You could also to add a non-clustered index on start and end dates and AssetId for optimal performance. By default, you could to add an end date as '9999-12-31' and, every time an asset have a new price, you end current period and starts a new one. I (personally) prefer this option.
- Stick with this schema and create an non-clustered index on EffectiveDate and AssetId. You'll need to build an subselect to get max date for assets with effective date less than your desired date, like this:

.

```
CREATE INDEX    IX_AssetPrice_EffectiveDate
                ON AssetPrice (EffectiveDate, AssetId) INCLUDE (Price)
DECLARE @AssetId int = NULL, @EffectiveDate datetime = '2012-01-11'
SELECT  AssetPrice.AssetId, AssetPrice.Price, AssetPrice.EffectiveDate
FROM    AssetPrice
JOIN    (
            SELECT  AssetId, MAX(EffectiveDate) EffectiveDate
            FROM    AssetPrice
            WHERE   EffectiveDate <= @EffectiveDate AND
                    (AssetId = @AssetId OR @AssetId IS NULL)
            GROUP BY AssetId
        ) Effective
        ON  AssetPrice.AssetId = Effective.AssetId AND
            AssetPrice.EffectiveDate = Effective.EffectiveDate
WHERE   (AssetPrice.AssetId = @AssetId OR @AssetId IS NULL)
```

Comment: Do note that queries with `between startdate and enddate` have very bad cardinality estimates because sql server does not know that there are not supposed to be overlaps for a certain key.